# How to convert Dalvik Bytecode to LLVM IR?

Tags: android, llvm, dalvik, dex2oat

I want to convert Dalvik bytecode to LLVM IR. I know google's ART can convert dalvik bytecode to oat file via dex2oat. Dex2oat is based on LLVM, and I only want to convert the dex to LLVM IR rather than oat.

So, could you show me the front end used in dex2oat? Or could you tell me any front end that can translate dalvik bytecode to LLVM IR? Any suggestion is really appreciated!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for dex2oat is available on [googlesrc.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/nougat-release/dex2oat/dex2oat.cc). If you download the git repo, you can see that the Android Runtime doesn't use LLVM at all, so you won't be able to use dex2oat to generate IR code from Dalvik.

[This Quora Answer](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-technical-details-of-the-Android-ART-runtime-introduced-in-Android-4-4/answers/10044855) indicates that LLVM support was removed in 2014.